# xquery select different tuple combinations

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to select the different combinations of countries out of the following example:

```
<neighbors>
    <neighbor>
        <country>Greece</country>
        <country>Albania</country>
    </neighbor>

    <neighbor>
        <country>Albania</country>
        <country>Greece</country>
    </neighbor>
</neighbors>
```

The idea is that, for this example, the combination Greece-Albania appears just once in the end result (regardless of the their order). As you can imagine, this must be done using XQuery.

Comment: Note: this is an exercise extracted from http://wwwiti.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/iti_db/lehre/adbm/9-practical.pdf

Comment: Are you asking Stack Overflow to do your homework?

Comment: @wst If I get an A I'll buy you a beer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"The idea is that, for this example, the combination Greece-Albania appears just once in the end result (regardless of the their)"*

Let me guess.. regardless of their order? If I guess correctly, then this is one possible way :

```
distinct-values(
    for $n in neighbors/neighbor
    let $countries := 
        for $c in $n/country
        order by $c
        return $c
    return string-join($countries, '-')
)
```

Basically, `$countries` variable stores sequence of all countries in individual `neighbor` in order, so that later on, `string-join()` results in the same string in case all `country` elements in current `neighbor` are the same, regardless of the order.

From this point, you can simply call `distinct-values()` on `string-join()` results to eliminate duplicate strings.

See a quick demo here : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/8a12250b915301a880dc743750de4492

Comment: Fair enough. But what if I wanted to keep the XML structure? Should I parse the resulting strings or is there any other way to do it without the string-join? Anyways, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint):

#### command line :

```
saxon-lint --no-pi --xquery '
  for $x in /neighbors/neighbor
  return string-join($x/country, "-")
' file.xml
```

#### output :

```
Greece-Albania
Albania-Greece
```